# How to undefine a zsh command created accidentally?

Tags: zsh, function

I wanted to search for the string '.vars()' in all my Python files, and somehow I redefined 'grep' as follows:

```
% grep .vars() *.py                                                         
% which grep
grep () {
    *.py
}
```

I have tried using `unset grep` and `export grep=/bin/grep` to correct this, without success. Can somebody explain what I've accidentally done?

NOTE: in Bash, it fails with:

> "syntax error near unexpected token `('".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a function definition. More precisely, this is the definition of two functions with the same code. It looks unusual because zsh has several extensions to the basic syntax of function definitions `name () { instruction; … }`:

- Zsh allows multiple names. `name1 name2 () { instruction; … }` defines both the functions `name1` and `name2` with the same body. I don't know of any other shell that supports this.
- Zsh allows `.` in function names (as does for example bash, but not dash or ksh93). Portable function names can only use ASCII letters, digits and underscore.
- Zsh allows any command as the body of a function. Some shells (in particular bash) require a compound command (which is all that POSIX requires).

  ```
  name () { instruction; … }
  ```

  is the most common form, where the body is a group.

  ```
  name () ( instruction; )
  ```

  is also portable and runs the body of the function in a subshell. Other compound commands are technically valid, for example

  ```
  name () if condition; then instruction1; else instruction2; fi
  ```

  is a POSIX-compliant function definition, but it's extremely unusual in practice.

  ```
  name () echo hello
  ```

  is a perfectly valid function definition according to zsh (and ksh and dash), but not according to POSIX or bash.
- A space before `()` is optional in all shells.

To undo the effect of `grep .vars() *.py`, unset the two functions.

```
unset -f grep .vars
```

or

```
unfunction grep .vars
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `ksh93` allows `.` in function names, but `.` has a special meaning there (used for object (called *types*) methods (called *discipline*)). See for instance `ksh93 -c 'typeset -T obj=(""() echo x); obj var; var.() echo y; var.'` which defines an `obj` type with a `""` method. We declare a `var` of that type and redefine its `""` method, and invoke it (which outputs `y`).

Answer (score 18):

This defines two functions, one named `grep` and the other named `vars`, whose body is `*.py`:

```bsh
grep .vars() *.py
```

To remove those functions --- and to unshadow `grep` --- you want:

```
$ unset -f grep .vars
```

From `man zshbuiltins`:

> ```
> unset [ -fmv ] name ...
>         ...
>         unset -f is equivalent to unfunction.
> ...
> unfunction
>         Same as unhash -f.
> ...
> unhash
>         ...
>         The  -f  option causes unhash to remove shell functions.
> ```

Comment: For completeness, the example also defined a function named `.vars`, although that's likely not shadowing anything.

Answer (score 5):

You've defined a *function*.  This is only valid in the current shell.

A simple function would be something like

```
f() echo hello
```

Now the "f" command will say hello

```
$ f
hello
```

The simplest way to clear it is with `unset -f` command.

In your case:

```
unset -f grep
```

Comment: "This is only valid in the current shell." -- meaning that the _simplest_ way to fix it is to exit the current shell.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe If you have set a lot of variables in your current shell or other functions they also would be lost if you exit the current shell. So it's probably not the simplest way.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, or do `exec zsh` which would reexecute `zsh` in the same process and  start fresh (except for the things that are inherited upon exec like environment variables, redirections, umask, cwd, some signal dispositions...). That would avoid the terminal disconnection.